# Split Multiline Textbox Step by Step

Tags: vb.net

how should i do if i want to add step by step values, I tried to make a code but I don't know how to make it useful,

Code:

```
 Dim line() As String = TxtMReadOnly1.Lines
 For i As Integer = 0 To line.Length - 2 Step 2 'Add this
 '''' 

  Dim Mynumber As Integer
    Dim isEven As Boolean
    Dim line() As String = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines
    For i As Integer = 0 To line.Length - 1 'Add this
        Mynumber = line.Length - 1
        If Mynumber Mod 2 = 0 Then
            isEven = True
            TxtOutpVal1.Text = Mynumber
        Else
            TxtOutpVal2.Text = Mynumber
        End If
    Next
```

Textbox:

```
7, 12, 14, 17, 19, 22, 24, 29, 32, 37, 40, 48, 49, 58, 62, 
5, 11, 13, 15, 19, 22, 24, 25, 35, 37, 38, 43, 45, 47, 50, 
2, 6, 8, 9, 18, 22, 23, 24, 35, 39, 45, 49, 52, 53, 58, 60, 
8, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 20, 26, 31, 32, 44, 47, 57, 60, 62, 
1, 7, 8, 13, 14, 16, 19, 30, 31, 33, 38, 48, 62, 64, 65, 67, 
1, 7, 11, 15, 21, 22, 24, 39, 42, 46, 50, 54, 59, 63, 66, 
3, 5, 8, 9, 16, 17, 27, 30, 31, 34, 35, 37, 40, 44, 46, 50, 
4, 6, 11, 17, 23, 33, 36, 39, 47, 51, 57, 59, 62, 63, 67,
```

> Expected Output: Textbox1.Lines:

```
7, 12, 14, 17, 19, 22, 24, 29, 32, 37, 40, 48, 49, 58, 62, 
 2, 6, 8, 9, 18, 22, 23, 24, 35, 39, 45, 49, 52, 53, 58, 60, 
1, 7, 8, 13, 14, 16, 19, 30, 31, 33, 38, 48, 62, 64, 65, 67, 
3, 5, 8, 9, 16, 17, 27, 30, 31, 34, 35, 37, 40, 44, 46, 50,
```

> Expected Output: Textbox2.Lines:

```
 5, 11, 13, 15, 19, 22, 24, 25, 35, 37, 38, 43, 45, 47, 50, 
 8, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 20, 26, 31, 32, 44, 47, 57, 60, 62, 
 1, 7, 11, 15, 21, 22, 24, 39, 42, 46, 50, 54, 59, 63, 66, 
4, 6, 11, 17, 23, 33, 36, 39, 47, 51, 57, 59, 62, 63, 67,
```

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to read the lines from one `TextBox` and copy the odd-numbered lines to a second `TextBox` and the even-numbered lines to a third `TextBox`?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place each line of `TextBox1` into an array. Then loop through that array and fill your additional textboxes based on the array index being odd or even.

```vb
'Create an array of each line in TextBox1
Dim arr = TextBox1.Lines

'Iterate through the array
For index = 0 To arr.Length - 1
    'If the array index is divisible by 2 then add line to TextBox2
    If index Mod 2 = 0 Then
        TextBox2.AppendText(arr(index) & Environment.NewLine)
    Else 'Add line to textbox3 if the index is NOT divisible by 2
        TextBox3.AppendText(arr(index) & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Personally, I would tend to add the lines to two collections and then, when done, convert them to arrays and assign them to the `Lines` properties of the target `TextBoxes`.